# How to use joins using associations in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine-plugins

I am trying to create a Redmine plugin built on Ruby on Rails. I have the following query which fetches the sum of time_entries of all the issues during an invoice.

```
SELECT SUM( t.hours ) 
FROM time_entries t
JOIN invoices i ON t.project_id = i.project_id
WHERE t.project_id = <current project id----@project.id>
AND i.id = <billing invoice id>
AND t.updated_on >  'i.created_at'
AND t.updated_on < 'i.due_date'
```

How can I store this query data inside invoices table column called time_spent or retrieve the results in the invoices view which lists all invoices along with the above query by invoice ID

The associations in model I created goes like this

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "invoices"
    set_primary_key "invoice_id"

    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "author_id"
    has_many :time_entries, :class_name => "TimeEntry", :foreign_key => "project_id"
```

In the Controller I am calling the model as

```
@invoices = Invoice.find(:all, :joins=>" INNER JOIN time_entries ON time_entries.project_id = invoices.project_id",:conditions => ["invoices.project_id = ? AND updated_on > ? AND updated_on < ?", @project.id, invoices.created_at, invoices.due_date])
```

I know the controller instance variable is totally messed up.

Somewhere I doing mistake. Can some one please help me with this.

Comment: What version of rails are you running?

Comment: I am using Rails 2.3.14 and Ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming Rails 3+ and MySQL, this should give you your each item in your @invoices collection an accessor named "time_spent" which will have the sum you are looking for.  It will not persist this info in the db, but it retrieves it for your view:

```
Invoice.where("invoices.project_id = ? AND invoices.updated_on > ? AND invoices.updated_on < ?", @project.id, invoices.created_at, invoices.due_date).select("SELECT invoices.*, SUM( time_entries.hours ) as time_spent").joins(:time_entries).group("invoices.id")
```

I'm guessing at < Rails 3 below:

```
Invoice.find(:all, 
:conditions => ["invoices.project_id = ? AND updated_on > ? AND updated_on < ?", @project.id, invoices.created_at, invoices.due_date],
:select=>"SELECT invoices.*, SUM( time_entries.hours ) as time_spent",
:joins=>[:time_entries],
:group=>"invoices.id")
```

*(hoping I typed this correctly.  If not, the gist is to use the "select" and "group" methods to get your result.)*

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sorry to mention that I am using Rails 2.3.14. The above code is slightly different. Invoice.where("invoices.project_id = ? AND time_entries.updated_on > ? AND time_entries.updated_on < ?", @project.id, invoices.created_at, invoices.due_date).select("SELECT invoices.*, SUM( time_entries.hours ) as time_spent").joins(:time_entries).group("invoices.id")   But with this I am getting error as "undefined method `where'"

Comment: I have another question that how can I save time_spent results in the database. I know this is a duplication, but it is a requirement as I have to integrate this with another application

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the following code.

```
Invoice.find(:all, :select => 'invoices.*, SUM( time_entries.hours ) as time_spent_on_issues', :joins=>" JOIN time_entries ON time_entries.project_id = invoices.project_id", :conditions => ["invoices.project_id = ? AND time_entries.updated_on > invoices.created_at AND time_entries.updated_on < invoices.due_date", @project.id])
```

BTW "miked" code helped a lot

Comment: Glad I could help, but your solution is not grouping by invoice.  Are you sure you're getting the right result?